# AngularJS show previous data on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's a [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dpecu5Ytn334I7XuST3b?p=preview) of the current situation.

I have a div in HTML where data is populated via JSON using ng-repeat. The JSON data is in nested form. In the div there's an anchor tag, clicking which renders the children of the parent node in the JSON into HTML.

[image]

On the click of the `"2 sub events"` here, the data of the sub-events are being populated.

Which is working fine. Now there's a button on the top of the page, I need to show the parent's data on the click of that button. I have no idea how to do that. Please help.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('MainApp',[])
.controller('treeGridController', function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {

$scope.tree_data = [];

var myTreeData = [{"DemographicId":1,"ParentId":null,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":2,"ParentId":1,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":3,"ParentId":2,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":4,"ParentId":3,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":5,"ParentId":3,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":6,"ParentId":2,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":7,"ParentId":6,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":8,"ParentId":6,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]},{"DemographicId":9,"ParentId":1,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":10,"ParentId":9,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":11,"ParentId":10,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":12,"ParentId":10,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":13,"ParentId":9,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":14,"ParentId":13,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":15,"ParentId":13,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]}]},{"DemographicId":16,"ParentId":null,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":17,"ParentId":16,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":18,"ParentId":17,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":19,"ParentId":18,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":20,"ParentId":18,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":21,"ParentId":17,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":22,"ParentId":21,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":23,"ParentId":21,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]},{"DemographicId":24,"ParentId":16,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":25,"ParentId":24,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":26,"ParentId":25,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":27,"ParentId":25,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":28,"ParentId":24,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":29,"ParentId":28,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":30,"ParentId":28,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]}]}];

$scope.tree_data = myTreeData;
console.log(JSON.stringify(myTreeData));

$scope.loadSubEvents=function(item){
        $scope.tree_data = item;
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tree_data));
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div>
    <h2><span><a href="#/">Go Back</a></span> Event Log</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div ng-repeat="data in tree_data" >
        <div>
            <h2>{{data.Name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>Items: <span>{{data.Items}}</span></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Failed: <span>{{data.Failed}}</span></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Execution: <span class="event-tree-log-result">{{data.Execution}}</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3 ng-if="data.children.length">
               <a href="" ng-click="loadSubEvents(data.children)">{{data.children.length}} sub events</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should load the parent data. One way of doing it is saving the parent when loading the child elements, and when you click "Go back" you simply reload the parent of the children. So you basically need to set the parent and then add a new function that loads the parent of a child.

```
$scope.loadSubEvents=function(item){
    // set parent
    item.parent = $scope.tree_data;
    $scope.tree_data = item;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tree_data));
}

$scope.loadParent = function() {
    if (!$scope.tree_data.parent)
        return;
    // load the parent
    $scope.tree_data = $scope.tree_data.parent;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tree_data));
}
```

And then you can update your HTML with a click handler

```
<div>
  <h2><span><a href="#/" ng-click="loadParent()">Go Back</a></span> Event Log</h2>
</div>
```